# Implementing Jquery from jsfiddle to own html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have found the following jsfiddle code:

```
<input type="text" id="meta_title" name="Disk_Space"> 
<input type="text" id="meta_description" name="RAM"> 
<input type="text" id="header" name="VRAM"> 
  <input type="submit" value="Create">
  <button id="save">save</button>
  <button id="load">load</button>
```

and

```
$('#save').on('click', function(){

    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).val();
       localStorage.setItem(id, value);

    });   
});

$('#load').on('click', function(){
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function(){    
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = localStorage.getItem(id);

        $(this).val(value);

    }); 
});
```

Which is perfect for what I need for a part of a project I am doing but I couldn't manage to get it to work in a html file. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you included jquery from cdn? or from any source

Comment: did it give any errors? have you included jQuery in your html?

Comment: Thanks guys I checked the code again and saw that I forgot to include the jquery.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is a column with name

> "External Resources"

on left hand panel, in which we can include the external JS, CSS file in the environment. And you forgot to add these external files in your code. Add these files and try again.